# Large gaps in chrome profiler flame chart

Tags: google-chrome, profiling, requestanimationframe

I am trying to speed up a slow three.js based app. Here's Chrome's flame chart for 2 frames:

[image: profiler flame chart]

I can see that my `draw` takes a long time, so that needs to be improved, fair enough. But what I do not understand is why there is such a lot of white space, during which nothing seems to be happening (and in particular, there is no GPU bar in that gap either). I am doing a `requestAnimationFrame` after every draw, and I'd expect that to get fired, not to wait for a full 250ms or so. Any way to find out what it is doing in these white gaps?